# What's the pun in this "Will a chick eat a banana" story?

Tags: puns

As reported by [The Observer](https://www.theobserver.com/2013/08/14/thoughts-views-in-praise-of-lousy-prose/), this 2013 Bulwer-Lytton Fiction Contest winner in the field of Vile Puns:

> “The veterinarian had suggested the tasty yellow fruit as a way to cure the undiagnosed lack of appetite that was ebbing away the very life of his fluffy little friend and Mark was fraught with anguish as he kept wondering, ‘Will a chick eat a banana?’” — Nancy Hoffman, Peaks Island, Maine

I can't see the pun, and only recently learned of [Chiquita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiquita) and their bananas. Is that all there is? A [Feghoot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feghoot), I suppose it is?

Comment: Got an answer? Post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

"Chiquita banana" is indeed the obvious pun, though of course one cannot *prove* this.

Answer (score 1):

"[Chiquita banana](https://archive.org/details/78_chiquita-banana_elsa-miranda-alfredo-antonini-and-his-viva-america-orchestra-mckenz_gbia0185276a/CHIQUITA+BANANA+-+Elsa+Miranda+-+Alfredo+Antonini+and+his+Viva+America+Orchestra.flac)" was a jingle/marketing name/slogan